# Is this insertion Sort?

Tags: python, algorithm

I was trying to implement insertion sort in python. I tried to understand the logic behind it and implemented it, it's proving me a sorted list at the end, but I doubt it is using insertion sort religiously. Can anybody confirm is it really insertion sort? Sorry if I sound silly.

```
u = [1,43,2,312,3,124,6,6]

for i in range(len(u)):
  for j in range(i,0,-1):
    if u[j] < u[j-1]:
      u[j-1],u[j] = u[j],u[j-1]


print(u)
```

I got this as the answer [1, 2, 3, 6, 6, 43, 124, 312]

Comment: More like bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is kind of bubble sort.

Here elements crawl to final position, making swaps with every oncoming one.

In insertion sort you extract element, find its position, shift whole range of elements, then put element into final place. So insertion sort performs shifts, "semi-swaps".